# Passing local variables into JTextbox

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am working on a programming challenge in Java, I have created a GUI with 3 boxes to enter numbers into, A, B, and C, I then have an Order of operations box where a user enters A,B,C, and whatever math operators they choose. When the Calculate button is clicked the result of the math operation is displayed in a results textbox.

Edit for a better explanation:

1. The user enters numbers into two or more of the fields for A, B, and C.
2. The user enters an expression into the Expression field.
3. When the user clicks the Solve button, the expression is evaluated and the result is              displayed in the Result field.

This is what I have so far.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

/*The string builder class allows the user to enter numbers into the UI
* The UI converts the Textbox input from strings to Floats and stores them in local variables
* A, B, and C
*/

    public class StringBuildUI extends JFrame
    {
        //declare all variables, constants, and components for the GUI

        private JPanel panel;                   // a panel to hold the gui components
        private JLabel messageLabelA;           // a label for the Text Field A
        private JLabel messageLabelB;           // a label for the Text Field B
        private JLabel messageLabelC;           // a label for the Text Field C
        private JLabel messageLabelR;           // a label for the Text Field results
        private JLabel messageLabelO;           // a label for the Text Field order of ops
        private JTextField boxA;                // a box to hold user input
        private JTextField boxB;                 // a box to hold user input
        private JTextField boxC;                // a box to hold user input
        private JTextField order;               // a box to determine order of operations
        private JTextField results;             // a box to hold user input
        private JButton calcButton;             // a button to calculate strings
        private JButton clearButton;            // a button to clear all text fields
        private JButton exitButton;             // a button to exit the program
        private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 750;   //window width
        private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 350;  //window height

/*
Constructor method for the GUI
 */

    public StringBuildUI ()
    {

        //set title
        setTitle("String Evaluator");

        //set size of the window
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT);

        //build the panel and add it to the frame and display the window
        buildPanel();
        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
    }

 /*
 build panel adds label, text fields and all the buttons to the panel
 */

    private void buildPanel()
    {
        //create the label for the text boxes, the boxes, and the buttons
        messageLabelA = new JLabel("A");
        messageLabelB = new JLabel("B");
        messageLabelC = new JLabel("C");
        messageLabelR = new JLabel("Results");
        messageLabelO = new JLabel("Order of Operations");
        boxA = new JTextField(10);
        boxB = new JTextField(10);
        boxC = new JTextField(10);
        order = new JTextField(10);
        results = new JTextField(10);
        calcButton = new JButton("calculate");
        clearButton = new JButton(" Clear Fields");
        exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

        //Group the buttons, and add them to the panel
        add(calcButton);
        add(clearButton);
        add(exitButton);

        //Create a panel and add components to it
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(messageLabelA);
        panel.add(boxA);
        panel.add(messageLabelB);
        panel.add(boxB);
        panel.add(messageLabelC);
        panel.add(boxC);
        panel.add(messageLabelO);
        panel.add(order);
        panel.add(messageLabelR);
        panel.add(calcButton);
        panel.add(clearButton);
        panel.add(exitButton);
    }
  /*
  Private inner class for event handling when the user clicks buttons
   */

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
          String inputA;    // holds user input from text box a
          String inputB;    // holds user input from text box b
          String inputC;    // holds user input from text box c
          Float   results;  // holds results of calculations
          Float A,B,C;      // holds converted strings for calculations
          //get string input
          inputA = boxA.getText();
          inputB = boxB.getText();
          inputC = boxC.getText();

          //Convert strings to integers
          A = Float.parseFloat(inputA);
          B = Float.parseFloat(inputB);
          C = Float.parseFloat(inputC);

         //get input from order of operations box
         Float inputABC;
         inputABC = order.getFloat();
        }
```

Did I convert to early?
I want to take A B and C and use them in my event handling for the calculate button so that the results will be based on the user input. In the back of my mind I am thinking that the only way I can base my math operations on the user input is if the variables A B and C are strings but I am not sure.

How can I pass the text input from the boxes and use them in my event handling?

Thanks.

Edited for answer to questions: the math operations are user defined, so I cannot put them into my event handler for my calculate button. I also have not started to code the calculate button because I am unsure of how to deal with user input.

Comment: If you can tell us what math operations you want to perform, it'd help.

Comment: What expression field? Should this field be a JComboBox so you can restrict the selection?

Answer (score 2):

You get data and convert at the right time, but I don't see you ever doing any calculations with your numbers or setting your results field text. Your ActionListener's actionPerformed needs a `results.setText(...)` method call at the end.

As an aside, you will want to learn and adhere to Java naming standards, including giving variables names that start with a lower-case letter. You'll also want to use names that are "self-commenting" and make your code easier to understand.

As another aside, you should almost never use float where a double will work as by doing this you gain much precision with little cost.

Comment: Thank you for the input, is it considered bad coding practice to comment that much? I was thinking that the amount of comments I am asked to use in school is a bit much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getText().trim() in order to remove any whitespace in the ABC order.

Moreover, you can also put result Box as setEditable(false).

Now about the question, you can use toCharArray() method of String to compare each of the 3 characters entered in the Order Box. Here's a short implementation of the method:

```
String s1 = "ABC";
char[] a = s1.toCharArray();
if(a[0]=='A' && a[1]=='B')
System.out.println("ABC");
```